# Fix Windows Server 2012 R2 system time?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012-r2, time

I have managed many Windows servers for several years, but I have never experienced anything like this:

We have a Windows Server 2012 R2 running as virtual machine on an Ubuntu Server with KVM.

In the Windows "Date and Time" settings, I have the correct time zone and set the correct time. But after some hours when I connect back to the server, the time is wrong by 2 hours (-2 hours). Even deactivating "Internet Time" (auto-sync with the time server) does not help.

When I go to the "Internet Time" tab and click the button to manually update the time with the time server, it shows the correct time as well. But after some hours, it is all wrong again.

What can I do to fix the server's time?

Comment: Please clarify, does the time zone change or the time itself? time zone has nothing to do with NTP. maybe theres some VM guest agent at play? what settings do you have on the host?

Comment: Have you checked _both_ the time _and_ the time zone _on the host_?

Comment: Is the server part of a domain or a workgroup?

Comment: @EliadTech it's only the the time that changes, the time zone remains correct.

Comment: @MichaelHampton just did, it says the correct time and CEST (which is correct)

Comment: "CEST" doesn't really mean much. It could be any of several different time zones, and with or without summer time. You're looking for something like `Europe/Paris`. Check `/etc/localtime` to see what it is pointing to. Or better yet, just do what should have been done originally, and set the timezone to UTC.

Comment: Last line says: CET-1CEST,M3.5.0,M10.5.0/3 - so I should be good? It says Europe/Berlin (on the host Ubuntu Server).

Comment: Maybe it's has something to do with the VM guest agent? is it installed? can you disable it for a while?

Comment: @andreas did you get it fix. I have the same problem on my server. Not in a domain and sometimes it goes back by 2 jours. I've tried different things but so far no luck

Comment: @TheEwook unfortunately not. Even adding a manual script didn't fix the issue...

Answer (score 2):

You first can check if your ntp serv is good in registery

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\W32Time\

If good check ntp service

> w32tm /query /status

If look good too, enable debug mode to get log

> w32tm /debug /enable /file:C:\w32time.log /entries:0-300 /size:20971220

Entries value is to get all type of info 
And size for the max size in octet of log