# Windows Server 2012 R2 time resetting by 2 hours (-2 hours)

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012-r2, windows-server-2012, time

The server doesn't host any VMs and doesn't belong in a domain.

In the Windows "Date and Time" settings, I have the correct time zone and set the correct time. But after some hours when I connect back to the server, the time is wrong by 2 hours (-2 hours). Even deactivating "Internet Time" (auto-sync with the time server) does not help.

When I go to the "Internet Time" tab and click the button to manually update the time with the time server, it shows the correct time as well. But after some hours, it is all wrong again.

There is a similar question ([Fix Windows Server 2012 R2 system time?](https://serverfault.com/questions/807585/fix-windows-server-2012-r2-system-time)) but it was a while back. perhaps somebody has a solution for this as this is causing us a lot of damaged as the time keeps changing.

What can I do to fix the server's time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, this is what I would try. I would point it to internal NTP servers or some well-known ones on the internet. This should keep your server in sync. I would also check and make sure your timezone is correct.

Configure your server to sync with an NTP server.

```
net stop w32time
w32tm /config /syncfromflags:manual /manualpeerlist:"ntpserver1 ntpserver2"
net start w32time
w32tm /config /update
w32tm /resync /rediscover
```

or https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/816042/how-to-configure-an-authoritative-time-server-in-windows-server

I would also check BIOS and make sure your time settings are correct.

Comment: Agreed, time must be the same everywhere and NTP server is always helps. http://www.pool.ntp.org/en/use.html

Comment: The issue came from the BIOS. Changing the time from the bios or setting the time in windows with the same timezone than the BIOS fix the problem. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Just as the LTS ran out, we started to experience these quirks.