# Windows Server 2012 R2 with hour/time issues

Tags: windows, time-synchronization, timezone

In my office, we have a Windows Server 2012 R2 with our SQL Server on it.
We are located in a UTC-7 timezone where we "suffered" DST (but not anymore).

Multiple times a day, our server clock adds 7 hours to itself to coincide with the hour on UTC+0, but the timezone on the server is still set to UTC-7.

We tried changing the time zone to Arizona (UTC-7), where they never used DST, unchecked time sync on any server, and multiple combinations with no success.

There is a similar post on [Windows Server 2012 R2 time resetting by 2 hours (-2 hours)](https://serverfault.com/questions/880395/windows-server-2012-r2-time-resetting-by-2-hours-2-hours) .

**EDIT:** When running the "Verbose command" it displays this (it's in spanish)

```
Indicador de salto: 0(ninguna advertencia) Capa: 2 (referencia secundaria - sincronizada mediante (S)NTP) Precisión: -6 (15.625ms por tick) Demora de raíz: 0.0471270s Dispersión de raíz: 7.7761138s Id. de referencia: 0x84A36001 (IP de origen: 132.163.96.1) Última sincronización de hora correcta: 05/05/2023 3:09:29 PM Origen: time.nist.gov,0x9 Intervalo de sondeo: 10 (1024s)

Desplazamiento de fase: 0.0245049s Frecuencia de reloj: 0.0156250s Equipo de estado: 1 (En espera) Marcas de origen de hora: 0 (Ninguno) Rol del servidor: 0 (Ninguno) Último error de sincronización: 2 (El equipo no se sincronizó porque solo tenía información obsoleta de hora.) Tiempo desde la última sincronización de hora correcta: 9246.2271045s
```

**EDIT2:** When running a log file for w32t, it showed this change when I, on purpose, changed the time on the server two hour to the futured and changed it back:

```
154256 22:42:52.4270465s - W32TimeHandler called: SERVICE_CONTROL_INTERROGATE
154256 22:43:02.5275511s - W32TimeHandler called: SERVICE_CONTROL_INTERROGATE
154257 00:43:10.8521663s - W32TimeHandler called: SERVICE_CONTROL_INTERROGATE
154257 00:43:20.9464343s - W32TimeHandler called: 
SERVICE_CONTROL_INTERROGATE

154257 00:43:31.0634751s - W32TimeHandler called: SERVICE_CONTROL_INTERROGATE

154257 00:43:35.9394523s - W32TmServiceMain: timeout

154257 00:43:35.9394523s - Sample Prepared at 133278074159394523 for peer time.nist.gov,0x9 (ntp.m|0x9|0.0.0.0:123->132.163.96.1:123)

154257 00:43:35.9394523s - NtpClient returned 1 samples.

154257 00:43:35.9394523s - Sample 0 offset:+00.0245049s delay:+00.0471270s dispersion:07.8731303s

154257 00:43:35.9394523s - Intersection successful with 0 dropped samples.

154257 00:43:35.9394523s -   0: Sample:0 SyncDist:238966938 SelectDisp:0

154257 00:43:35.9394523s - Sample 0 chosen. Select Dispersion:00.0000000s STC:7022766

154257 00:43:35.9394523s - ClockDispln Update: *STALE*(NextSTC=7022766 <= LastUTC=7022766) Hold(1)

154257 00:43:35.9394523s - W32TmServiceMain: waiting 1024.000s

154256 22:43:38.7084419s - W32TimeHandler called: SERVICE_CONTROL_INTERROGATE

154256 22:43:48.8421763s - W32TimeHandler called: SERVICE_CONTROL_INTERROGATE
```

Comment: I forgot to add, we already checked the BIOS clock and it's also set to UTC-7 with no DST.

Comment: Time synchronization isn't related to DST or time zones. It only uses UTC. There is verbose logging for the time service. That needs to be enabled and would be a minimum to pursue this to determine the source.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/identity/turn-on-debug-logging-in-windows-time-service  If this server is part of a domain, it must synchronize time with Active Directory, no exceptions. There needs to be output of the configuration from `w32tm /query /status /verbose`. If it is a virtual, the virtualization platform time synchronization must be disabled.

Comment: There's no domain controller or Active Directory, it's not a virtual server or any kind of virtualization environment. What really bothers me is that the change is always 7 hours to the future and that we are in a UTC-7 timezone.

Also, all of this happens exactly the same wether the timesync is on or not.

I'll try that verbose thing and let you know.

Comment: There's another server that runs some tools Apps, ERP, etc.
It also runs Windows Server 2012 R2 on Arizona's UTC-7 and the time on it doesn't change.